# Mysql and php sum of values from colum depending on date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table structured like this:

1st column: `id;`

2nd column: `date;`

3rd column: `integer value;`

The date can vary from 2010-01-01 to 2014-12-20 for example.

In the PHP code i have defined two variables in `"Y-m-d" format`, let's say the values are:

```
$first_date = "2011-10-17"

$last_date = "2014-11-04"
```

How can I get the sum of the values from the 3rd column for each month in the interval defined by the `$first_date` and `$last_date` ?

Comment: You need a sum(row) where mydate between date1 and date2?

Comment: An example: [id=1][date=2011-10-17][value=2];

[id=2][date=2011-10-18][value=2];

[id=3][date=2011-11-04][value=3];

[id=4][date=2011-11-12][value=3];

The sum for "2011-10" is 4;
The sum for "2011-11" is 6;

These are the values that I need;

Comment: In that case @Gordon's query will do the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do a SQL query like this:

```
select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, sum(value)
from table t
where date between $first_date and $second_date
group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m')
order by yyyymm;
```

I would recommend that you parameterize the query rather than putting the variables directly into the SQL string.

Comment: I tried this query on my table that has aproximaty 100 entries with date varying from 2014-02-14 to 2014-11-08: "SELECT date_format(entry_date, "%Y-%m") AS yyyymm, sum(active_entry_value) FROM active_table WHERE entry_date BETWEEN 2010-10-10 AND 2014-12-12 GROUP BY date_format(entry_date, "%Y-%m") ORDER BY yyyymm". I am not getting any results from it (MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0021 sec)). I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.